# what does write_back_intra_pred_mode() function from libavcodec do?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec

Bellow is a function from ffmpeg defined in libavcodec/h264.h:

```
static av_always_inline void write_back_intra_pred_mode(const H264Context *h,
                                                        H264SliceContext *sl)
{
    int8_t *i4x4       = sl->intra4x4_pred_mode + h->mb2br_xy[sl->mb_xy];
    int8_t *i4x4_cache = sl->intra4x4_pred_mode_cache;

    AV_COPY32(i4x4, i4x4_cache + 4 + 8 * 4);
    i4x4[4] = i4x4_cache[7 + 8 * 3];
    i4x4[5] = i4x4_cache[7 + 8 * 2];
    i4x4[6] = i4x4_cache[7 + 8 * 1];
}
```

What does this function do?

Can you explain the function body too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function updates a frame-wide cache of intra prediction modes (at 4x4 block resolution), located in the variable `sl->intra4x4_pred_mode` per slice or `h->intra4x4_pred_mode` for the whole frame. This cache is later used in `h264_mvpred.h`, specifically the function `fill_decode_caches()` around line [510-528](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/h264__mvpred_8h_source.html#l00510), to set the contextual (left/above neighbour) block info for decoding of subsequent intra4x4 blocks located below or to the right of the current set of 4x4 blocks.

[edit]

OK, some more on the design of variables here. sl->mb_xy is sl->mb_x + sl->mb_y * mb_stride. Think of mb_stride as a padded version of the width (in mbs) of the image. So mb_xy is the raster-ordered index of the current macroblock. Some variables are indexed in block (4x4) instead of macroblock (16x16) resolution, so to convert between units, you use mb2br_xy. That should explain the layout of the frame-wide cache (intra4x4_pred_mode/i4x4).

Now, the local per-macroblock cache, it contains 4x4 entries for the current macroblock, plus the left/above edge entries, so 5x5. However, multiplying something by 5 takes 2 registers in a lea instruction, whereas 8 only takes one, so we prefer 8 (more generally, we prefer powers of 2). So the resolution becomes 8(width)x5(height) for a total of 40 entries, of which the left 3 in each row are unused, the fourth is the left edge, and the right 4 are the actual entries of the current macroblock. The top row is above, and the 4 rows below it are the actual entries of the current macroblock.

Because of that, the backcopy from cache to frame-wide cache uses 8 as stride, 4/3/2/1 as indices for y=3/2/1/0 and 4-7 as indices for x=0-3. In the backcopy, you'll notice we don't actually copy the whole 4x4 block, but just the last line (AVCOPY32 copies 4 entries, offset=4[y=3]+8[stride]*4[x=0]) and the right-most entry for each of the other lines (7[x=3]+8[stride]*1-3[y=0-2]). That's because only the right/bottom edges are interesting as top/left context for future macroblock decoding, so the rest is unnecessary.

So as illustration, the layout of i4x4_pred_mode_cache is:

```
x x x TL T0 T1 T2 T3
x x x L0 00 01 02 03
x x x L1 10 11 12 13
x x x L2 20 21 22 23
x x x L3 30 31 32 33
```

x means unused, TL is topleft, Ln is left[n], Tn is top[n] and the numbered entries ab are y=a,x=b for 4x4 blocks in a 16x16 macroblock.

You may be wondering why TL is placed in [3] instead of [0], i.e. why isn't it `TL T0-3 x x x` (and so on for the remaining lines); the reason for that is that in the frame-wide and block-local cache, T0-3 (and 00-03, 10-13, 20-23, 30-33) are 4-byte aligned sets of 4 modes, which means that copying 4 entries in a single instruction (COPY32) is significantly faster on most machines. If we did an unaligned copy, this would add additional overhead and slow down decoding (slightly).

Comment: But what are the 40 members of `sl->intra4x4_pred_mode` and why this function copies some of its members to another index?

Comment: intra_pred_mode_cache is for the current block (16x16 pixels). intra_pred_mode is the frame-wide context. It copies it to have all relevant members in the block decoding loop in a smaller memory area which improves performance due to improved memory caching, but still have access to all frame-level members for subsequent block decoding iterations.

Comment: if  `intra_pred_mode_cache` is for current macroblock why it has 40 elements not 16? and still I don't understand the indexes in the above function and also the array `h->mb2br_xy`.

Comment: I have a video with frame size 854x480. 854/16 = 53.375 so `mb_stride` should be 54. But if I print the value of `mb_stide`' I get 55. What is happening?

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/h264__slice_8c_source.html#l01348 - most contextual arrays need one entry padding on the left so it can be initialized for contextual purposes for the leftmost macroblock in each row.